# xsl:include not working

Tags: php, xml, xslt, xml-parsing

I've been trying for hours now but I just can't get the include to work. All I'm left with is a blank page. Take a gander at the code:

something.xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
    <xsl:output 
      doctype-public="-//WAPFORUM//DTD XHTML Mobile 1.0//EN" 
      doctype-system="http://www.wapforum.org/DTD/xhtml-mobile10.dtd"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:element name="html">
            <xsl:element name="head">
                <xsl:element name="title">Something</xsl:element>
            </xsl:element>

            <xsl:element name="body"> 
                <xsl:attribute name="onload">
                    <xsl:text>initialize();</xsl:text>
                </xsl:attribute>

                <xsl:element name="div">
                    <xsl:attribute name="id">
                        <xsl:text>main</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:attribute>                                    
                </xsl:element>              

                <xsl:include href="blob.xsl" />

            </xsl:element>

        </xsl:element>

    </xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

blob.xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
    <xsl:output 
      doctype-public="-//WAPFORUM//DTD XHTML Mobile 1.0//EN" 
      doctype-system="http://www.wapforum.org/DTD/xhtml-mobile10.dtd"/>

    <xsl:template match="*">
            <xsl:element name="div">
                <xsl:attribute name="id">
                    <xsl:text>navoptions</xsl:text>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and the php code

```
<?php
    $xml = new DOMDocument();   
    $xml->load('file.xml');

    $xsl = new DOMDocument;
    $xsl->load('something.xsl');

    $proc = new XSLTProcessor();
    $proc->importStyleSheet($xsl);

    echo $proc->transformToXML($xml);
?>
```

**Update:** This is clearly not getting anywhere. As far as my research goes, you cannot import multiple xsl stylesheets when using PHP. On the other hand, does anyone know if this is possible using ColdFusion?

Answer (score 3):

xsl:include must be a direct child of xsl:stylesheet.

If your XSLT processor isn't giving you an error message for this then you need a better XSLT processor.

Answer (score 1):

Besides what Michael Kay says, when I use php and include/import xslt you can help it to resolve the uri by setting a xml:base attribute to that element.

I.e. if the xslt's are in /var/www/html/views/ then the xsl:include looks something like:

<xsl:include href="blob.xsl" xml:base="/var/www/html/views/" />

See: https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#uri-references

Answer (score 0):

The XSLTProcessor probably doesn't know how to resolve the  line. You have to include it manually or hint the XSLTProcessor.

http://php.net/manual/en/xsltprocessor.importstylesheet.php

Code from a comment that should work:

```
<?php 

# LOAD XML FILE 
$XML = new DOMDocument(); 
$XML->load( 'data.xml' ); 

# START XSLT 
$xslt = new XSLTProcessor(); 

# IMPORT STYLESHEET 1 
$XSL = new DOMDocument(); 
$XSL->load( 'template1.xsl' ); 
$xslt->importStylesheet( $XSL ); 

#IMPORT STYLESHEET 2 
$XSL = new DOMDocument(); 
$XSL->load( 'template2.xsl' ); 
$xslt->importStylesheet( $XSL ); 

#PRINT 
print $xslt->transformToXML( $XML ); 
?>
```

Comment: Tried it, all it does is load the second stylesheet alone. The first one is ignored.

Comment: Also when I tried assigning the first and second stylesheets to different variables I got the blank page again. The comment on that page actually says that multiple stylesheet loading is not supported.