# Apache Camel XSLT: how to use xsl-templates with imports?

Tags: xml, xslt, import, apache-camel, filepath

#### Description

I have a `xml`-file which i want to transform with a `xsl`-template by using `Apache Camel` and the `xslt`-component.

The xsl-file-structure of the stylesheet is more complex with dependencies and uses imports itself, like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"   xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" [...]>
       <xsl:import href="..\base.xsl" />
       <xsl:import href="..\componetA\xyz.xsl" />
       <xsl:import href="..\componetB\abc.xsl" />
       [...]
       {$var_defined_in_base_xsl_import}
       [...]
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Then i have a simple Camel-route, like:

```java
from("file:{{absolute_path.xml.inbox}}?noop=true&fileName=myXmlFile.xml")
   .to("xslt:file:{{absolute_path.xsl.template}}");
```

using:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.9.0</version>
</dependency>
```

#### The Problem

For testing, i call with Apache Camel the absolute path. The main file of the xsl-template is successfully loaded, but i get an error, that variables (like `{$var_defined_in_base_xsl_import}`) which are defined in the imported xsl-files can not be loaded. In this example all imported files, like `base.xsl`, `xyz.xsl` and `abc.xsl` are not loaded / available in the Camel xslt context. It seems Camel just takes the xsl-template from the specified path and then runs the transformation at another context / not related to the original path. I looked up the [Apache Camel documentation](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/xslt-component.html) but didn't find an option which would fix this problem.

**Has anyone an idea, how to transform a xml-file with a xsl-template which uses imported files on a Apache Camel route?**

#### Ideas

I also played a bit with the paths in the xsl-template, like these examples:

```
<xsl:import href="../base.xsl" />
<xsl:import href="C:/Users/myname/test/base.xsl" />
<xsl:import href="C:\Users\myname\test\base.xsl" />
<xsl:import href="C:\\Users\\myname\\test\\base.xsl" />
<!-- EDIT: also tried: -->
<xsl:import href="file:///C:/Users/myname/test/base.xsl" />
<xsl:import href="../base.xsl" xml:base="file:///C:/Users/myname/test/subfolder" />
<xsl:import href="../base.xsl" xml:base="C:/Users/myname/test/subfolder" />
<!-- with copying base.xml in same directory "subfolder" -->
<xsl:import href="base.xsl" />
<xsl:import href="base.xsl" xml:base="file:///C:/Users/myname/test/subfolder" />
<xsl:import href="base.xsl" xml:base="C:/Users/myname/test/subfolder" />
```

None of these examples worked and i guess it is the wrong approach to change the paths in the templates. I think there should be a way to fix this with Apache Camel settings like to preload the whole stylesheet with its dependencies and then use that compiled xsl or something like that but i have no clue how. I would be thankful if somebody has an idea for me.

Comment: Maybe you need give Apache Camel more context using xml:base. See i.e.: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66245566/3710053

Comment: I am not familiar with Apache Camel but do note that the href is a URL so the only syntax supposed to work as a URL in your samples is `href="../base.xsl"` with a forward slash, for the absolute file path you would need to use absolute file URLs e.g. `href="file:///C:/Users/myname/test/base.xsl"` I think to have any chance in the Java world (a Microsoft XSLT processor might work with Windows file paths).

Comment: Thx for your fast responses. I tried both solutions, i used `<xsl:import href="file:///C:/Users/myname/test/base.xsl" />` or `<xsl:import href="../base.xsl" xml:base="file:///C:/Users/myname/test/subfolder" />`. Both didn't work. I still guess Apache Camel takes the file out ot path context so the references will fail. And for notice, the original xsl stuff is from an public organisation and they use "\" instead of "/" in the paths and it works also with other tools, so it may not be the problem. i tested it with both variants and it made no difference, but i'm no expert?

Comment: I suppose you don’t need to use file:/// in the xml:base attribute

Comment: It's true that many XSLT processors will accept filenames (including backslashes) where the spec says a URI is required; but this is certainly not something you can rely on.

Comment: @SiebeJongebloed i removed file:/// in xml:base as you recommend, but still doesn't work. I updated the list in the questions with the two variants. Still i guess there should be a solution to fix this in Apache Camel itself but i have no clue how to do this.

Comment: If at the end nothing works, you could write a xslt that merges the import's before bringing them to Apache Camel.